# proper way to show sum of many values on page

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel as my backend service and need to know the proper way of calculating the summation of many(at least 100,000) records from MySQL database.
To get it more clear, assume there are 100,000 goods in database changing by time. 
On the main page of the client, I want to show the sum of the price of all goods. Could you tell me how can I do this with least process on the server?

Comment: Using MySQL `SUM`. But if you're going to do that often I would strongly consider saving the sum somewhere and updating it every time new goods are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel provides an easy way to get the sum of some values of the database. Just add this function to your query and you have a column with your sum.

```
->sum('price')
```

To update the sum of the prices of all goods on the client side you can define a route, which could be used for an AJAX request to update the value.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do sum of the goods one using mysql sum in to query and another one is to do sum in to PHP side either looping through goods or using array_sum etc. I would give a try to both case and will do benchmark with both option to find out best performance one.

Client side Javascript is always an open option to do sum and display it.